# Can I use a DVD-R to burn a regular audio CD?

Tags: audio, dvd, recording, cd

I want to burn a regular audio disk (similar to the pre-recorded audio disks) that can be played in any player, not just a computer, using a DVD-R.

Would this work?

And, if so, is it safe to assume that I will be able to fit a lot more songs on it than a 700 MB CD?

In other words, once I finish burning it, the file format on it should be `.cda`.

Comment: No, CDs and DVDs require different types of laser.

Comment: To be clear, when you say "DVD-R", are you referring to the physical disk or the drive used to write it?

Comment: Just a note for you, you usually can write to a CD-R using a DVD-R drive. So just put a normal CD-R in the drive and use your preferred music burning software.

Comment: Thank you to all. Wow! I love this unique forum - so many helpful answers so quickly from caring people! Thanks to everyone. 

Yeah, I have reverted to a CD to burn the music. Clearly, the DVD does not do the job, though I wish it did. :-) Merry Christmas to one and all.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you could somehow burn an “audio DVD”.

However, you would most definitely not be able to play it in a CD drive. On DVDs, the information is packed much more densely. Regular CD drives cannot read them.

`.cda` files don’t exist by the way. It’s just Windows’ way of showing tracks on an audio CD.

Comment: Actually, I do have a DVD R/W drive. So, would that work?

Comment: You can play the disc as if it's an audio disc with a DVD player, but a CD (audio) player will not work if the content is burnt to a DVD.

Comment: Actually, the software refused to burn it to a DVD, anyway. :-) It asked me to insert a CD. That answers my question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty difficult to find compatible hardware today, but there actually were multiple attempts to make a way to do this back in the early 2000's. (Even though their goal was primarily higher quality not capacity, capacity was also improved, especially by using double-layer discs.)

- Sony and Philips [Super Audio CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Audio_CD) - this format is not compatible with DVD player hardware, but its discs are somewhat similar.
- All the other DVD manufacturers' [DVD-Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Audio) - **reading this format is still supported by some players**, and the Wikipedia article lists some burning software, though most of it is not available anymore.

Neither of the formats ever gained enough popularity, studies showed that no one could tell the difference in the supposedly higher quality, and both were declared dead around 2007.